# Unable to get the last last commit details from Drone

Tags: docker, drone.io

I am integrated Drone CI/CD with BitBucket server and suppose to push the Docker images to Gitlab Private Registry. Currently, I was stuck with Drone CI/CD I am unable to get the last commit details through Shell script. 
I have to build the Docker images when code changes done in the BitBucket and I have to tag it with the Drone build number.

Currently, I was stuck at unable to get the commit number through Shell script, based on the previous build number I can only tag the image with Docker image.

Any Suggestions for how to achieve this.

Below is the example of tagging of the image
Docker tag image name with date and build number
"MyImage.version.date.with_Build number:latest